# starting gitblit service on ubuntu 17.04 results in active (exited)

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-17.04

I am trying to run a service "gitblit" like this:

> sudo service gitblit start

when I check the status I see this:

> Active: active (exited) since Fri 2017-09-01 16:25:16 CEST; 4s ago

In my syslog I find this:

```
Sep  1 16:25:16 git-01 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Gitblit repository server...
Sep  1 16:25:16 git-01 gitblit[7817]: Starting gitblit server
Sep  1 16:25:16 git-01 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Gitblit repository server.
```

Any Idea how to fix this?

Comment: Now I got error java.net.SocketException: Permisson Denied

Comment: Ok problem was solved by using 8080 as port not 80